# Why does classes.dex in the built APK contain classes from java package

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, dex

Due to the "64k method reference limit" on Android, i'm using the "Analyze APK" feature from Android Studio to better understand what is the code that gets built into my app's APK (under classes.dex).

Among all the packages i am familiar with, i see that my dex also includes classes from java.* packages. I assumed this code already exists on the device as part of the Java runtime.

Why does this code get included? attaching a screenshot that shows the packages that were added to classes.dex

[image]

Comment: Can you show your proguard file?

Comment: it's rather long: https://pastebin.com/faszk03L